# How can I automatically initialize all the scalar variables in Perl?

Tags: perl, variables, initialization

Perl [automatically initializes variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260703/when-does-perl-auto-initialize-variables) to `undef` by default.

Is there a way to override this default behavior and tell the Perl interpreter to initialize variables to `zero` (or some other fixed value)?

Comment: Initializing variables to `undef` is still an initialization.

Comment: May I ask _why_ you would want to do this?

Comment: @Zaid: The full story - I am reading Code Complete (which mentions always initializing variables while declaration, if possible) and was looking at one of my old files that uses a lot of counters that I had all initialized to `zero` initially but later removed all the unnecessary initializations. I am thinking about reintroducing all the initializations, and asked this question to find a better way to do it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The recommendation in Code Complete is important for language such as C because when you have

```
int f(void) {
   int counter;
}
```

the value of `counter` is whatever happens to occupy that memory.

In Perl, when you declare a variable using

```
my $counter;
```

there is no doubt that the value of `$counter` is `undef` not some random garbage.

Therefore, the motivation behind the recommendation, i.e. to ensure that all variables start out with known values, is automatically satisfied in Perl and it is not necessary to do anything.

What you do with counters is to increment or decrement them. The result of:

```
my $counter;
# ...
++ $counter;
```

is well defined in Perl. `$counter` will hold the value `1`.

Finally, I would argue that, in most cases, counters are not necessary in Perl and code making extensive use of counter variables may need to be rewritten.

Comment: When did *rewritten* turn into *refactored*, anyway? ☺

Answer (score 12):

As far as I know, this is not possible (and shouldn't be, its even more dangerous than `$[`).

You can initialize your variables as follows to cut down on boilerplate:

```
my ($x, $y, $z) = (0) x 3;
```

or move initialization to a function:

```
sub zero {$_ = 0 for @_}

zero my ($x, $y, $z);
```

or even:

```
$_ = 0 for my ($x, $y, $z);
```

Comment: it is the index that arrays start from.  it was there to make perl behave like awk by setting it to 1.  it is deprecated and warns and only has file scope and must be set at compile time because of all the bugs it could cause in unrelated code.  perldoc perlvar for more info

Comment: Can't see why you would need to initialize something to zero at its point of declaration.

Comment: @tchrist => If the first expression a variable is used in is a comparison or complex mathematical expression (think iterator sub with closed over state), you will get a warning on undef values.  In those cases, initializing at the declaration site seems as good a place as any.

Comment: well, perhaps. But I usually keep them at zero when I want to test them boolishly, or use ++ or += on, none of which requires such.

Answer (score 5):

No. Doing this can lead to some very scary and hard-to-decipher bugs, so it's not a good idea to change behaviour like this anyway.

In Perl, you can declare variables right when you need them for the first time, so there isn't generally a need to declare them first (with or without initialization) and then using them later. Additionally, operators such as `++` will work with undefined values equally well as zero, so you don't need to initialize counters at all:

```
# this is perfectly legal:
my $counter;
while ($some_loop)
{
    $counter++;
}
```

However, I can insert a plug for [Moose](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Moose) by mentioning that you can achieve automatic initialization of attributes in your Moose classes:

```
package MyClass;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Moose;

has some_string => (
    is => 'rw', isa => 'Str',
    default => 'initial value',
);

has some_number => (
    is => 'rw', isa => 'Int',
    default => 0,
);
__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;
1;

package main;
my $object = MyClass->new;
print "string has value: ", $object->some_string, "\n";
print "number has value: ", $object->some_number, "\n";
```

prints:

> string has value: initial value
>   number has value: 0

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a concrete reason for wanting to do this, or is it simply "because *Code Complete* says I should"?

If the former, please share the reason and we can discuss properly Perly ways to accomplish your real goal.

If the latter, please remember that *Code Complete* is a set of guidelines for programming in C, not Perl.  Perl is not C and has its own set of strengths and weaknesses, which also means that it has a different set of... and I hate to use this phrase... best practices.  Guidelines appropriate for one language do not necessarily apply to the other.  "Always initialize variables (if possible) when you declare them" is a sound practice in C, but generally unnecessary in Perl.

Answer (score 0):

Why would I not simply initialize a variable just prior to its first use?

Answer:  I keep lots of "stock code" lying about.  The whole "just declare it" when first used doesn't really work with my production style. I might write something where "my $FirstVariable = 0;" is included as the first line of a code block; then later, insert something *above* that block that also references $FirstVariable.  Now I've broken my routine by moving blocks of code about.

If I "declare" all the variables I'll be needing at the top, then I don't have to worry about rearranging blocks of code killing the procedure because of preceeding necessary variable declarations.

Also, if the variable declarations are at the top, I can easily comment one declaration out, then try running the routine.  This can be handy for troubleshooting large, complex programs because it will produce a list, complete with line numbers, of every place that the [now undeclared] variable is referenced.  When I'm done looking everything over, I just delete the comment character and I'm back in operation!